# Load reference data in second level cache using hibernate post application deployment

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache, spring-jms

Application is a Spring MVC, with hibernate.
I am using ehcache as second level cache for hibernate.
I am able to cache the data during server startup. But as the data to be cached is very large, so the requirement is to load the data in cache after the application is deployed so that users do not need to wait for application to start.
We are looking to use either JMS or asynchronous thread to load data in cache.
Please suggest on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is successfully implemented using Spring JMS.
Message was send to the JMS listener at Spring's `contextRefreshedEvent`. Finally, listener called DAO to load data asynchronously.